# How can i upgrade my react-native and its node modules too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I upgrade my react-native and its node modules too? I run npx react-native upgrade
and it update my react-native version but I want that it upgrade my node modules too with react-native because of that I am facing errors I tried deleting node modules but still its not working
and I know that its a version issue

Answer (score 0):

1. You could delete package-lock.json and reinstall packages
2. Change versions in package.json manually